# create a command using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

i'm starting using discord.py and i don't understand why my bot does not respond to  my `test` command .the bot is starting correcly and says his line in the channel while starting but do not react to my command

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')



class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
        channel = client.get_channel(123456789)
        await channel.send("online")
     
        
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('test')
```

thank you !

Comment: You never defined `client` before referencing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your bot as **bot**. However, in your MyClient class you have put *client.get_channel* which should be bot.get_channel. You're saying it starts fine and sends the message to the channel which is weird. You might have had trouble saving the code or something

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that you don't necessarily need a class attribute; you can use `@bot.event` just fine like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

@bot.event
async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
        channel = client.get_channel(123456789)
        await channel.send("online")
     
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send('test')
```

Or, the error in your original code is in two places. `discord.Client` is inbuilt; instead you should be declaring bot as well as indentation of `bot.command`:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')

class MyClient(bot):
   
   @bot.event
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
        channel = client.get_channel(123456789)
        await channel.send("online")
     
        
   @bot.command()
    async def test(ctx):
        await ctx.send('test')
```

I think that should work. The first one I am sure will work 100%; the second one, not so much since I haven't run these codes right now since I am busy. If you get any other error, feel free to ask. Plus, I don't think there is any benefit in declaring a class.